# Show line errors in codemirror?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I just upgraded CodeMirror to latest and have the following code now breaking:

```
        // clear previous errors from editor window
        for (var i = 0; i < layoutCodeEditor.lineCount(); i++) {
            layoutCodeEditor.clearMarker(i);
            layoutCodeEditor.setLineClass(i, null, null);
        }

        var valid = JSLINT(code);
        var jsLintError = "";
        if (!valid) {
            jsLintError = JSLINT.error_report(JSLINT.data());
            _.chain(JSLINT.errors).compact().each(function(e){
                // show markers in the code edit window against lines with Jslint errors
                layoutCodeEditor.setMarker((+e.line) - 1, "●", "errors");
                layoutCodeEditor.setLineClass(+(e.line) - 1, null, "errorLine");                    
            })
        }
```

seems like the setMarker/clearMarker and setLineClass functions have been removed. What's their equivalents now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These changes, among many others, are covered in the [Upgrading to version 3](http://codemirror.net/doc/upgrade_v3.html) page on the CodeMirror site.

The marker functions have changed as a consequence of moving to multiple gutters:

> ## [Gutter model](http://codemirror.net/doc/upgrade_v3.html#gutters)
>
> In CodeMirror 2.x, there was a single gutter, and line
>   markers created with `setMarker` would have to somehow coexist with the
>   line numbers (if present). Version 3 allows you to specify an array of
>   gutters, [by class name](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#option_gutters), use [`setGutterMarker`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#setGutterMarker) to add or remove markers
>   in individual gutters, and clear whole gutters with [`clearGutter`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#clearGutter).
>   Gutter markers are now specified as DOM nodes, rather than HTML
>   snippets.
>
> The gutters no longer horizontally scrolls along with the content. The
>   fixedGutter option was removed (since it is now the only behavior).

The line class change is more straightforward:

> ## [Line CSS classes](http://codemirror.net/doc/upgrade_v3.html#lineclass)
>
> The `setLineClass` method has been replaced by
>   [`addLineClass`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addLineClass) and [`removeLineClass`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#removeLineClass), which allow more modular control
>   over the classes attached to a line.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I hadn't seen that but it makes perfect sense.